# Serializing a long string in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have a class which implements WritableComparable class in Hadoop. This class has two string variables, one short and one very long. I use `writeChars` to  write these variables and `readLine` to read them but it seems like I get some sort of error. What is the best way to serialize such a long String in Hadoop?

Comment: Should I append a line terminator character at the end of each string variable so that the ``readline`` can recognize when each ends?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use byteswritable to make it more efficient. Check the below custom key which has BytesWritable type as callId.

```
public class CustomMRKey implements WritableComparable<CustomMRKey> {
private BytesWritable callId;
private IntWritable mapperType;

/**
 * @default constructor
 */
public CustomMRKey() {
    set(new BytesWritable(), new IntWritable());
}

/**
 * Constructor
 * 
 * @param callId
 * @param mapperType
 */
public CustomMRKey(BytesWritable callId, IntWritable mapperType) {
    set(callId, mapperType);
}

/**
 * sets the call id and mapper type
 * 
 * @param callId
 * @param mapperType
 */
public void set(BytesWritable callId, IntWritable mapperType) {
    this.callId = callId;
    this.mapperType = mapperType;
}

/**
 * This method returns the callId
 * 
 * @return callId
 */
public BytesWritable getCallId() {
    return callId;
}

/**
 * This method sets the callId given a callId
 * 
 * @param callId
 */
public void setCallId(BytesWritable callId) {
    this.callId = callId;
}

/**
 * This method returns the mapper type
 * 
 * 
 * @return
 */
public IntWritable getMapperType() {
    return mapperType;
}

/**
 * This method is set to store the mapper type
 * 
 * @param mapperType
 */
public void setMapperType(IntWritable mapperType) {
    this.mapperType = mapperType;
}

@Override
public void readFields(DataInput in) throws IOException {
    callId.readFields(in);
    mapperType.readFields(in);

}

@Override
public void write(DataOutput out) throws IOException {
    callId.write(out);
    mapperType.write(out);
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj instanceof CustomMRCdrKey) {
        CustomMRCdrKey key = (CustomMRCdrKey) obj;
        return callId.equals(key.callId)
                && mapperType.equals(key.mapperType);
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
public int compareTo(CustomMRCdrKey key) {
    int cmp = callId.compareTo(key.getCallId());
    if (cmp != 0) {
        return cmp;
    }
    return mapperType.compareTo(key.getMapperType());
}
```

}

To use in say mapper code say you can generate the key of BytesWritable form using  something as following :-

You can call as :

CustomMRKey customKey=new CustomMRKey(new BytesWritable(),new IntWritable());
     customKey.setCallId(makeKey(value, this.resultKey));
     customKey.setMapperType(this.mapTypeIndicator);

Then makeKey method is something like below :-

```
public BytesWritable makeKey(Text value, BytesWritable key) throws IOException {
    try {
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteKey = new ByteArrayOutputStream(Constants.MR_DEFAULT_KEY_SIZE);
        for (String field : keyFields) {
            byte[] bytes = value.getString(field).getBytes();
            byteKey.write(bytes,0,bytes.length);
        }
        if(key==null){
            return new BytesWritable(byteKey.toByteArray());
        }else{
            key.set(byteKey.toByteArray(), 0, byteKey.size());
            return  key;
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw new IOException("Could not generate key", ex);
    }
}
```

Hope this may help.